# UserForm Run-time-error | Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, listbox, userform

I made a UserForm with Excel. It has TextBoxes and CheckBoxes and command buttons.
UserForm starts with TextBoxes and after that some CheckBoxes come up and TextBoxes goes on. `cmdAddData_click` is for to send data to sheet. I searched a lot but I'm a newbie around here.

When I want to send data it gives

> run-time error, Application-defined or object defined error.

Appreciate for all helps.

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 0).Value = txtDate.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = txtName.Text

'after 34 textboxes, now for checkboxes

If cbxADSL.Value = True Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 35).Value = "Yes"
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 35).Value = "No"
End If


If cbxAlarm.Value = True Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 36).Value = "Yes"
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 36).Value = "No"
End If


'after checkboxes, now for textboxes

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 122).Value = txtFirstContact.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").Cells(lastrow + 1, 123).Value = txtLastContact.Text


End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Hey :). At the third line which starts with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers").........

Comment: Ah, of course: `Cells` is used like `Cells(row, column)` but you wrote `Cells(lastrow + 1, 0)`. The issue is that column numbering starts with `1` and a column `0` does not exist. • Additionally I recommend to use a [`With` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) for `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers")`. So you don't have to repeat it over and over.

Comment: So much thanks mate ! It worked! but I don't understand the other advice :)

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `Cells(lastrow + 1, 0)`.

`Cells` is used like `Cells(row, column)` but column numbering starts with `1` and a column `0` does not exist.

Furthermore you can reduce your code using a [With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) and the [IIf function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function):

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("00. Active Customers")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 0).Value = txtDate.Text '<-- column number must be fixed
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = txtName.Text

        'after 34 textboxes, now for checkboxes
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 35).Value = IIf(cbxADSL.Value, "Yes", "No")
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 36).Value = IIf(cbxAlarm.Value, "Yes", "No")    

        'after checkboxes, now for textboxes
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 122).Value = txtFirstContact.Text
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 123).Value = txtLastContact.Text
    End With
End Sub
```